# Maven + Jboss + SmartGWT application

Tags: java, maven, gwt

there! My idea is too plain but I couldn't find a solution. I am used to build web projects using maven. I asseble a project and deploy it into jboss, start AS and watch a result throught web-browser. I used to use JSP. Now I decided to study build web-proj using GWT/SmartGWT technology. I've looked throught the Internet and come across a lot of explanation examples. Some of them are based on using Ant, some of them - used Eclipse + GWT plugin. I prefer to use Intellij IDEA. I saw that IDEA contains GWT-application where I can create a simple HelloWorld project. But this is injected in IDEA, and I can easily run it from IDEA. I mean it is not suit for me, cosa I want to assemble it using maven, and deploy it into jboss on my own. I really can't do it and don't realize how to manage it. I hope you'll give me an example or a link where I can get how to build a project by my "scheme")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem really is, but I think you might want to use [Maven GWT plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/) to build your project.

Comment: I need an HelloWorld example using maven-assembling + GWT =)

Comment: Using the archetype will create you what you need. [link](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html)

Comment: eah, thx! I've looked thought "Project organization" and find what I need)